# Hide and show DIV's from different columns depending on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have form that must hide() fields (divs in example) depending on what value was selected from #note-type. I know how do hide block only from one column, but don't understand how to hide elements in different columns one time? Code below please tell me what is my js mistake as I'm very new to this language.

```
<form method="POST" action="#">

<select name="note_type_id" id="note_type">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<div class="flex">
    <div class="first-column">
        <div>
            <div>some info</div>
            <div id="class-one">sdsdsds</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-column" id="class-two"> 
        <div>some info</div>
        <div>some info</div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
            toggleFields();
            $("#note_type").change(function () {
                toggleFields();
            });
        });
        function toggleFields() {
            if ($("#note_type").val() === "5")
                $("#class-one").hide();
                $("#class-two").hide(); - Problem is here
            else if ($("#note_type").val() === "6")
                $("#class-one").hide();
                $("#class-two").hide(); - Problem is here
            else
                $("#class-one").show();
                $("#class-two").show(); - Problem is here
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: not php related, please dont tag with unrelated languages

Comment: got it. I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else):

> if (condition)
>
> statement1
>
> [else
>
> statement2]
>
> statement1
>
> Statement that is executed if condition is truthy. Can be any statement, including further nested if statements. To execute multiple statements, use a block statement ({ ... }) to group those statements. To execute no statements, use an empty statement.

Hence, your issue is related to lack of block (i.e.: {})

```js
$("#note_type").on('change', function (e) {
    toggleFields();
}).trigger('change'); // in this way you call immediately the function...


function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#note_type").val() === "5") {
        $("#class-one").hide();
        $("#class-two").hide();
    } else if ($("#note_type").val() === "6") {
        $("#class-one").hide();
        $("#class-two").hide();
    } else {
        $("#class-one").show();
        $("#class-two").show();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="#">

    <select name="note_type_id" id="note_type">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>

    <div class="flex">
        <div class="first-column">
            <div>
                <div>some info</div>
                <div id="class-one">sdsdsds</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-column" id="class-two">
            <div>some info</div>
            <div>some info</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I get the thing!

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your function, as far as I've understand, you need to hide those divs in case of 5+6 choices, otherwise show 'em

```
function toggleFields() {
    switch ($("#note_type").val()) {
        case "5":
        case "6":
            $("#class-one").hide();
            $("#class-two").hide();
            break;
        default:
            $("#class-one").show();
            $("#class-two").show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Your code doesn't contain functional brackets `if ([expression]) { ... [do something] ... }`.